# Converting Integer column to Date Column

Tags: python, pandas, date

In my import file one of the column has a date, if I view the same column in the dataframe, its converted into integer. How do I convert back to the date format.

In the data file, the column looks like 'Oct-17' but when I view in the dataframe it looks like '43009'. How do I change in Python from integer to Date so my data looks like 'Oct-17'

Appreciate for your help

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `pandas` & `date`).

Comment: It would help if you said how you import the file...

Comment: dataset = pd.read_excel("ACRDataloadv2.xlsx")                                                                                                       df1=dataset
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)                                                                                     'Commitment Line End Month' is the column, In the import file the value is in the date format for example 'Oct 2018' but in the Dataframe it's showing as integer 43009

Answer (score 0):

Use [`xlrd`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), once you read in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date_String':[43009,43000,42345,43134,43917]})

import xlrd

df['Date'] = df['Date_String'].apply(lambda x: xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(x, 0))
df['MMMYY'] =df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))

print(df)

   Date_String       Date   MMMYY
0        43009 2017-10-01  Oct-17
1        43000 2017-09-22  Sep-17
2        42345 2015-12-07  Dec-15
3        43134 2018-02-03  Feb-18
4        43917 2020-03-27  Mar-20
```